# Toggling SVG with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I've been writing code for a extension that is suppose to basically automate a few clicks on a website. I have been able to automate every button except for the initial first click which is on a SVG "button".

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 18 18" class="buy-toggle ">

<path d="M16.6,13.2L9,17.4l-7.6-4.2L9,0.5L16.6,13.2z M9.1,9.4l-5,3l5,2.5l5-2.6L9.1,9.4z M6,8.9L9,7l3,1.9L9,4.4L6,8.9z"></path>
```

This is the code for the SVG Toggle itself. I have tried using the usual ElementbyClass and DocumentJquery, However neither wants to work with getting the menu toggled open.

Comment: Show your JavaScript.

Comment: There is no code for this, Since Literally everything I have tried is not working. Can't click(); can't add it to a variable and then click();, Can't add a listener, Since it thinks of the SVG as a null value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if understand you correctly, but if you want to attach click listener to `path` of your svg, something like this work:

```js
var s = document.getElementById('s1');
s.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 18 18" class="buy-toggle ">
  <path id="s1" d="M16.6,13.2L9,17.4l-7.6-4.2L9,0.5L16.6,13.2z M9.1,9.4l-5,3l5,2.5l5-2.6L9.1,9.4z M6,8.9L9,7l3,1.9L9,4.4L6,8.9z"></path>
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt but it gave back the same error I have been having.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

It seems like no listener or outside code can interact with it, Which I am finding odd

Comment: Nevermind, There was a Hidden <a> Tag that was the real code for the SVG button, Not what I had posted earlier. It worked once I replaced the "s1" with the new ID tag, Thank You!

Comment: have you tried from snippet above to click the path(black area)?
It gave correct listener
but ok, as long as you can correct the problem :)
regards